# Python Background Thread Timer

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

```
def run_timer(duration):
  import threading
  import time
  import sys
  
  class Timer:
    def __init__(self , duration):
      self.duration = duration
      self.remaining_time = duration
      self.timer_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_timer)
      self.timer_thread.daemon = True
      self.timer_thread.start()

    def run_timer(self):
      start_time = time.time()
      while self.remaining_time > 0:
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        self.remaining_time = max(0,self.duration - elapsed_time)
        self.display_time()
        time.sleep(1)
      print("Timer fin")

    def display_time(self):
      minutes , seconds = divmod(int(self.remaining_time) , 60)
      print(f"Time remaining: {minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}" , end="\r")

    def stop_Timer(self):
      pass

  timer = Timer(duration)

  try:
    input()
    timer.stop_Timer()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    timer.stop_Timer()
```

Above is the code I have tried, it somewhat works but defo not as I want it to.. I don't know how to fix I just tried youtube google chatgpt nothing helped been working on this damn tiemr than my whole program itself.

Basically what i want is the user to be able to exit the timer while it still running in the background (counting down) and if the user for example in my case (timer is used for a game and i want to put a delay so user cant just do a thing over and over again) and if the user re tries to do that it ll show them how long they still have to wait (timer still counting down) until they can do it again or if it has finished they can just continue

Comment: Be more precise. What happens, what exactly should happen?

Comment: im working on a logistics text-based game and i don't want the user to be able to just do deliveries over and over again i want the user to need to take a break like a 2 minute timer and if he tries to do it again the timer will start and after it started he can for leave the timer and do something else in the program but then if he tries to do a delivery again if the timer didn't end it will show how long they have left until they can do it again but if it had they can continue (when you start the timer and then leave the timer it still displays remaining time and it displays over other text)

Comment: If I understand it right, your actual problem is to allow user input while some other output (remaining time) is shown and continually updated. This is not possible with the simple `input`/`print` functions (without making a mess). You need a library for advanced handling of terminal/console like curses or a GUI library like tkinter.